# Debian LiveUSB created with `Rufus` (windows) works but not when created with `dd`

Tags: debian, dd, live-usb, debian-installer, debian-cd

I am trying to create a bootable USB using the hybrid iso image of debian from 
https://cdimage.debian.org/images/unofficial/non-free/images-including-firmware/9.3.0-live+nonfree/amd64/iso-hybrid/

The command I used on my empty flash drive at /dev/sdb is:

```
sudo dd if=debian.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=4M
sync
```

Source: https://www.debian.org/CD/faq/#write-usb

But the resulting USB is not detected during booting and not shown in the bootable devices list. I also verified using `gparted` that the bootable flag is already set.

As an alternate, I switched to a windows PC and downloaded the utility RUFUS from https://rufus.akeo.ie/ and this worked like a charm and is able to boot correctly.

I obviously hate to switch to a windows machine everytime I need to create a live usb.

Can someone please verify where my mistake is with the `dd` command procedure?

Comment: Did you make sure your USB stick was UNMOUNTED first? bs=4M sysnc is used on Macs. Try: sudo dd bs=4M if=input.iso of=/dev/sd<?> conv=fdatasync . Presumably you changed "user" you your own username

Comment: I have never created a bootable medium on linux with dd. It might be possible, however i dont know how.

If you have a graphical user environment in your linux machine i can recommend the ubuntu package usb-creator-gtk. It always reliably did the job for me.
That package is probably also available on debian if thats the distro your using.

Comment: I would also [check](https://www.debian.org/CD/verify) the checksums (md5, sha256,...) of the ISO file.

Comment: @Alex338207 md5sum was thoroughly checked.

Comment: @UXELDUXEL Using dd was not my invention, rather the official instruction itself https://www.debian.org/CD/faq/#write-usb usb-creator-gtk is is unfortunately not working for iso's other than ubuntu..

Comment: @arochester I took the instructions directly from official debian FAQ https://www.debian.org/CD/faq/#write-usb on creating usb on Linux platform, and the disk was properly unmounted before dd. Yes, <user> was correctly used.

Comment: @LovesProbability i could swear that i have used usb-creator-gtk to make debian disks before. Did you actually try it? However what your saying makes some sense perhaps i used a different tool, cant remember. Would love feedback on this.

Comment: Have you tried installing Etcher on Linux instead? https://www.maketecheasier.com/linux-live-disks-etcher/